# Mid and Instr Function in c#

Tags: c#

I am facing an issue while converting the Mid and Instr function of VB in c#
I have a string array which splits my Connection String, like this:

```
(0)"Data Source" = 192.123.21.2\sql2014"
(1)"Initial Catalog = IPETDB"
(2)"User ID = sa"
(3)"Password = M******"
(4)"Connection Timeout = 5"
```

I want to retrieve the value of "Initial Catalog"

in VB:

```
For i = 0 To arrkey.Length -1
   Retval = UCase(Mid(arrkey.GetValue(i), 1, Instr(arrkey.GetValue(i), "=", 
   ) - 1))

If Trim(retval) = Trim("INITIAL CATALOG") Then
    DBName = Mid(arrkey.GetValue(i), Instr(arrkey.GetValue(i), "=", ) + 1)
End If
Next
```

In c# by `.GetElement(1)` i can achieve the mentioned index value, but i want the value after "=" ie: the Database name in my senario (IPETDB).

Comment: Have you considered using `string.Split` to split the string into the bits before and after the `=`?

Comment: Have you considered using the `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` (or equivalent for other DBs) to work with the connection string instead?

Comment: No i didn't try that though.

Comment: @jon Skeet : I am splitting it once with ' ; ' , how can i further split my string array into bits before and after the = ?

Comment: @Toto: Each string in your array consists of `key = value`, right? So call `string.Split` on each of those strings, as you process it. (Although if this is just a connection string, chances are there's already a framework class that will handle all of this for you in a simpler way.)

Comment: Ahh! that worked..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest analogues of `Mid` and `InStr` functions are [Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2), accordingly.

However, you can achieve a needed result in more easy way:

```
        List<string> strings = new List<string>()
        {
            "Data Source = 192.123.21.2\\sql2014",
            "Initial Catalog = IPETDB",
            "User ID = sa",
            "Password = M******",
            "Connection Timeout = 5"
        };

        foreach (var str in strings)
        {
            var tokens = str.Split('=');
            if (tokens.Length != 2)
                continue;
            if (tokens[0].Trim() == "Initial Catalog")
                DBName = tokens[1].Trim();
        }
```

Comment: How can i check it with upper case?

Comment: Use `.ToUpper`: `tokens[0].Trim().ToUpper() == "INITIAL CATALOG"`

Comment: wooh!.. That helped :) . if you can please upvote my question.